# Change the name shown in task manager of the process for python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, process, windows-10, rename, taskmanager

I am trying change the name displayed in task manager for my script in python 3.8
The default name of the process is just Python.

procname does not work and wont install and psutil just gives a lot of error.
I am using thonny as my ide on windows 10.

The following do now work it only show in the ide and not in the  task manager

```
 import setproctitle

setproctitle.setproctitle('Change title')


print(setproctitle.getproctitle())
```